# Where to begin with multi-threaded programming with c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to implement my own IRC client as a personal proejct and I realized I needed a way to read and write from the socket at the same time. I realized I could have a reading thread which reads from the socket in the background and puts data in a queue and I could have another thread which writes data from a queue to the socket. However I have no idea on how to start with multithreaded programing or how to do it with c++. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Title and content don't match in my opinion, or you're changing questions in the middle of your post, which is confusing.  Do you want to learn how to work with sockets [async or synchronous, btw?] or do you want to learn how to spawn a new thread?

Comment: @ItzWarty, I think it's pretty clear... the OP wants to learn how to spawn a new thread in C++. The stuff about sockets is just to give us the context in which he's going to use the threads.

Comment: "C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading" will be published shortly (september). The first draft is quite good, it presents the new threading facilities of C++0x (Boost.Thread "closely follow[s] the proposals presented to the C++ Standards Committee"). The author is Anthony Williams http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/thread/

Comment: Threading is the right way to parallelize CPU-intensive computation.  It's the wrong way to parallelize I/O, you just pay extra for context switches and synchronization/locking for no reduction in complexity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C++ threads, [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html) (which is the basis for the upcoming `std::thread`) is the best way to go. That said, while threads might be the correct solution for your particular case, I just wanted to throw it out there that [select](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) and non-blocking sockets are a common approach to interleaving the reading/writing and writing of multiple sockets without the need for threads. The [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html) library wraps the functionality of select and non-blocking sockets in a cross-platform, C++ manner.

Comment: Once there are boost.threads, it's only a small step to boost.asio which would handle those sockets for OP too.

Comment: Thanks for the information about boost::thread and non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 5):

It's specific to C and *nix, but I can't think of a better starting place than [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/).  "You will learn from the Jedi Master who instructed me."

You'll learn the basics of reading and writing to sockets, and more importantly, that multi-threading isn't necessarily the right answer.

Comment: @thyrgle, I'm answering the "implement an IRC client in C++" question that was semi-hidden in the OP.  I *am* geniunely trying to be helpful here.  The text of the question implies that the OP is very early in the learning phase on this material.  It's hard to ask the right question at that stage.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [Qt Threading](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads.html).  It is highly documented with really excellent sample code on almost every feature.  Plus they are LGPL licensed now and will run on most every platform and include the source code with the binaries.  They also have very good network supoort.

Whatever way you choose, make sure that they have good documentation and samples

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) libraries. In my opinion they are easier to get on with than boost and have excellent documentation. These libs provide great frameworks for writing multithreaded networking code. You can learn a lot from them and get up and running pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). It has portable abstractions for **many** operating system functions (*nix, Windows etc): BSD sockets, Threads, Mutexes, Semaphores etc - write once compile anywhere (See [ACE_OS namespace](http://www.riverace.com/ACE/ace55/html/ace/namespaceACE__OS.html) of ACE).

It has **a lot** of network application patterns you can use (ACE_Reactor would be good for the beginning) but you can use the portable abstractions of the BSD functions (socket, send, recv, close, select - they are enough for your IRC client)

As previously mentioned [boost](http://www.boost.org/) is also an option and usually **any** cross-platform library providing portable abstractions for each operating system (I can think of [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) for the graphical part - if you want to do this).

And one advice: **do not** use threads unless you really need to. They are not as easy as it seems.

When referring to the network communication I believe that what you want to do is easily achievable in a single threaded application(ACE_Reactor helps you a lot here but you are free to use the BSD socket functions). First understand how sockets work, then - if you want to - understand how the reactor makes use of sockets in its network application patterns([ACE_Reactor](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/classACE__Reactor.html) works in conjuction with [ACE_Event_Handler](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.5/html/ace/classACE__Event__Handler.html) objects).

Hope it helps!